# Print PDF file without opening print dialog in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to print my PDF file without opening Print dialog in ASP.NET Web forms.

My requirement is I have some PDF files on my server and I want to print that file on button click but without opening the Print window.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is concatenate the PDF files into one file and then print it, showing the printer dialog once at the beginning of the process. .**NET PDF libraries that have this functionality.**

```
PdfDocument.Combine("Output.pdf", "doc1.pdf", "doc2.pdf", "doc3.pdf");
```

**Please refer this documentation may help you** [Print without Dialog](https://www.neodynamic.com/articles/Print-PDF-from-ASP-NET-directly-to-default-printer-without-print-dialog/)

Comment: @S Dhanissh In any case i can not open print window or print dialog and I need to print file one by one

Comment: @ParitaNavadiya refer documentation may help you.

Comment: @S Dhanissh I have refer your document and try but it's not work for me